# Parse- data is corrupt in loop of requests

Tags: parse-platform, mutex

I started to use Cloud code in parse.
And I problem. I found out the if I run loop of calling to Cloud code function 
the functions call in parallel so in this case some value is corrupt.

Their is way to use mutex, semaphore in parse?
Or maybe another option that prevent from the data to corrupt. 
Cause I put ACL but users can run loop of request and the number will change..

for example in this case I run this loop.
This loop corrupt the data that fun1 sets.

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
       Parse.Cloud.run('fun1', {
            itemId: 'b1A6joANKL'
        }).then(function(){ Parse.Cloud.run('fun1', {
             itemId: 'b1A6joANKL'
        })}).then(function(){ Parse.Cloud.run('fun1', {
             itemId: 'b1A6joANKL'
        })});
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what's your problem. You are trying to run parallel code and you are having racing issues ?

Comment: I dont try to run parallel loop. parse run it parallel.

Comment: Try posting some code, it's pretty cloudy what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

For loops in CloudeCode (Recursion), i'm using local function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("MyCloudCodeFunc", function(request, response) {
    localCloudLoopFunction();
});

function localCloudLoopFunction(){
    localCloudLoopFunction();
}
```

Comment: I dont want to do loop. But if someone make a loop from outside he can corrupt all the data. 
So I have security problem